# WPF - Pushing Enter on Textbox to execute a command

Tags: c#, wpf

I've seen countless ways to do this - and they all seem more or less the same. But i cannot get this to work at all.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Assetbox" Text="{UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Return" Command="{Binding IPfind, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

This is an amalgam of several things i saw, and just about the point where i hit the wall and decided to ask for help. Please - what am i screwing up here?

Pushing enter does nothing at all, The IPfind command works just fine if i run it from a button click, but i'd like to avoid that. Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The keybinding is working for me, silly question: does the textbox have focus when you press Return?

Comment: Not silly at all, to be honest - i'm new at this, but it doesn't have "has focused" on it... should it? the way it's supposed to work is that i type a hostname into a textbox, and "pushing the button" will populate the ip to a different textbox. But instead of clicking the button, would like to push "enter" instead.

Comment: Well there's only few options for this not to be working. The `TextBox` needs to be the active control, so you should see the blinking caret in the text field. Past that the `TextBox` needs it's `DataContext` set to the viewmodel that has your `ICommand`. That usually would be inherited, but if your having more issues your full xaml and viewmodel would help troubleshoot.

Comment: Well, i fixed it using

                `<TextBox x:Name="Assetbox" KeyDown="IPfind" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>`

and then adding an if statement to the command `if (e.Key == Key.Enter)`

Comment: Ah I miss understood, you must be going to an event handler. The key binding you had originally was expecting to be bound to an `ICommand` property.

Comment: All good - you gave me the idea anyway :) thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Was going about it all wrong, I changed the properties of the text box to:

```
 <TextBox x:Name="Assetbox" KeyDown="IPfind" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="120" VerticalContentAlignment="Center" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
```

And added an if statement to my command to look for key presses

```
private void IPfind(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
```